# I can't build android-27 , tool-27.0.2 with travis.CI

Tags: travis-ci

Can any one help me?

Stuck from my side.

https://travis-ci.org/XinyueZ/mvvm-template/jobs/313586340

I can 't build (./gradlew test) it.

my `yml` is:

```
language: android
android:
  components:
    - tools
    - platform-tools
    - build-tools-27.0.2
    - android-27
    - add-on
    - extra
licenses:
    - 'android-sdk-license-.+'
jdk:
    - oraclejdk8
script:
    - ./gradlew :repository:testMockDebugUnitTest :repository:testProdDebugUnitTest :repository:testProdReleaseUnitTest
before_cache:
    - rm -f $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/modules-2.lock
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.m2
    - $HOME/.gradle/caches/
    - $HOME/.gradle/wrapper/


    buildToolsVersion = '27.0.2'
```

I have tried 27.0.1  as well, same failed.

I had one or three times successed, just 2 hours later, something went wrong.

same `yml`,  no change.

[See here](https://travis-ci.org/XinyueZ/mvvm-template/jobs/313586340)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SDK Platform Android 8.1.0 - can't download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47719420/sdk-platform-android-8-1-0-cant-download)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It seems Google uploaded a new version of the `android-27` package and the checksum is now different and the download fails. For the moment, you need to install it yourself using the `sdkmanager` CLI instead. Here's what you would need to add to your .travis.yml file:

```
before_install:
- yes | sdkmanager "platforms;android-27"
```