# SDK Platform Android 8.1.0 - can't download

Tags: android

Android SDK manager fails with this message:

> Downloading SDK Platform Android 8.1.0, API 27, revision 1 Download
>   finished with wrong size. Expected 65606517 bytes, got 65738431 bytes.

Is there a workaround?

**Edit**: Download worked correctly from AndroidStudio.

Comment: I had the same issue. After several attempts (4), it finally installed for me.

Answer (score 39):

When download fails, you can notice a temp folder for this path:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp". There should be a file called "platform-27_r01.zip". Copy it out and extract the "android-8.1.0" folder.
The next step, rename it to "android-27". Then, copy it to the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms".

Open the SDK manager again, you will notice it is solved.

Comment: Very glad to hear that. :-)

Answer (score 9):

EDIT (For others):

Using the `sdkmanager` tool instead of the deprecated `android` tool prevents the validation error. It looks like someone at Google forgot to update the checksums of SDK Platform 8.1.0 for the `android` tool.

EDIT (For Travis CI):

Current recommended workaround is to add

```
before_install:
  - yes | sdkmanager "platforms;android-27"
```

to your .travis.yml file to use the `sdkmanager` to download the API 27 platform.

---

I just encountered the same issue a few hours ago while using Travis CI, so I manually uninstalled and reinstalled my local `android-27` package, expecting the reinstallation to fail with the same error. To my surprise though, it succeeded when I ran `./sdkmanager.bat "platforms;android-27" --verbose` after uninstalling it.

The only difference I can tell is Travis CI using the deprecated `android` command instead of the modern [`sdkmanager`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html) command, but the deprecated `android` command correctly redirects to the `sdkmanager` command in my local SDK.

My exact error message, which is the same:
`Download finished with wrong size. Expected 65606517 bytes, got 65738431 bytes.`

There is now an issue on the Travis CI GitHub: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8874

Comment: This answer is only valid if you are using Travis.

Comment: @LoPoBo I believe the general solution is to use the `sdkmanager` tool instead of the deprecated `android` tool.

Comment: @MitchellSkaggs Great, that solved it! Maybe you could add that to the top of your answer, as the question does not mention Travis? :)

Comment: any solution for CircleCI?

Comment: What are these commands? I just use the "SDK Manager.exe" GUI tool

Comment: @OrionEdwards These commands are required to install packages headlessly (in a  CI server). Developers should use the GUI within Android Studio typically.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same issue. A clear cache (tools->options..->Clear cache) and restart of sdk manager solved it.

Comment: So if you are not one of those people, you need to change .... yourself :-)

Comment: I was about to try all those manual stuff with unzipping and copying, but occasionally noticed this underrated suggestion =) So, it is very helpful to read through ALL the answers before trying the most voted solution.

Answer (score 2):

Leo Li's instructions worked for me, too. Thanks for the info!

When download fails, you can notice a temp folder for this path:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp". 
There should be a file called platform-27_r01.zip. Copy it out and extract the android-8.1.0 folder.

The next step, rename it to android-27. Then, copy it to the path.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms"

Answer (score 1):

Leo Li 
Thank you so much, it work for me ;-)

When download fails, you can notice a temp folder for this path:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp".
```

There should be a file called `platform-27_r01.zip`. Copy it out and extract the `android-8.1.0` folder.

The next step, rename it to `android-27`. Then, copy it to the path.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms"
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Had this same issue three weeks ago. Tried again last week. SDK 8.1 installed properly with Android SDK Manager. Google apparently included an incorrect checksum that has been subsequently corrected. Try the download again, it should work.

Comment: I try today and still fail.

Comment: As 19/01 still fails... What did help was Leo Li post! As the download was completed successfully but the checksum bug prevent the sdk from applying it. Following his instructions manage to work, once you restart sdk it says everything is ok.