# Visual Studio Android SDK Manager Android 8.1.0 API 27 error "Download finished with wrong size. Expected 65606517 bytes, got 65738431 bytes"

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, travis-ci

Have Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10. When attempting to install new Android API with Android SDK manager, the error in title occurs. Searching has yielded this answer:

[Edit Travis.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47719420/sdk-platform-android-8-1-0-cant-download)

This answer does not tell which one to edit. When searching C:\ for this file, I get 8 results:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeAdapter\844e64fa\node_modules\agent-base.travis.yml

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeAdapter\844e64fa\node_modules\ws.travis.yml

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeAdapter\844e64fa\node_modules\ultron.travis.yml

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeAdapter\844e64fa\node_modules\https-proxy-agent.travis.yml

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeAdapter\844e64fa\node_modules\http-proxy-agent.travis.yml

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeAdapter\844e64fa\node_modules\extend.travis.yml

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeAdapter\844e64fa\node_modules\concat-map.travis.yml

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeAdapter\844e64fa\node_modules\agent-base.travis.yml

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeAdapter\844e64fa\node_modules\concat-map.travis.yml

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeAdapter\844e64fa.travis.yml

Which one of these travis.yml files need to be edited as shown in the referenced answer to fix the Android SDK Manager install issue?

NOTE: Would have commented on the linked question if my reputation was high enough.

Comment: What about uninstall and install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google appears to have fixed the checksum, so the download now works with Android SDK manager.