# Download finished with wrong size. Expected 65606517 bytes, got 65738431 bytes

Tags: android, android-studio

I got this error when Trying to install `SDK Platform Android 8.1.0, API 27, revision 1`:

```
Download finished with wrong size. Expected 65606517 bytes, got 65738431 bytes.
```

I see from another answers that the solution is to add this to `travis.yml` file:

```
before_install:
    - yes | sdkmanager "platforms;android-27"
```

There is no such a file in the android directory and I do no know where to create it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SDK Platform Android 8.1.0 - can't download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47719420/sdk-platform-android-8-1-0-cant-download)